# How to access ComplexType Variables

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I got a WSDL, and some variables are sended to me,
but I don't know in which way to acces them....

The WSDL part that I need looks like this:

```
<s:element name="SaveRelation">
   <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="persistance" type="tns:Relation"/>
      </s:sequence>
   </s:complexType>
</s:element>

<s:complexType name="Relation">
   <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GUID" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ParentRelation" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RelationName" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="VisitAddress" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DeliveryAddress" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Person_1" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Person_2" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Person_3" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Person_4" nillable="true" type="s1:guid"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Country" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ChamberOfCommerceNumber" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VatNumber" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Fax" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Telephone" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InternetAddress" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="E_mail" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Obsolete" type="s:boolean"/>
   </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>

<wsdl:message name="SaveRelationSoapIn">
   <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaveRelation"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

These variables are sended to my server, I need to process them and put them in the database, and then return ok/fail based on succes or failure.
I've got everything working, accept for accesing the variables.

I've tried things like `$parameters.GUID , $parameters[0][0], $parameters[0].GUID` , the 1st returns ArrayGUID, the second return nothing/empty, the third also returns nothing/empty.

So to sum it up, **I don't know how to acces the variables in the Relation ComplexType.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to var_dump() the response from the service?  You should be able to determine how to reach the values if you can see the structure of the response data.

Comment: I get all kinds of weird signs in my soapUI output when I try this, it's a class thats get sended to my server instead of a variable....

Comment: Are you using PHP's native soap client to interact with this service?  http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php  You can use it to call the service method and it makes it easier to deal with the response too

Comment: This is not a client, like the question says, this is a server, A delphi application sends a request along with the class/complextype parameter and then the server is going to process the parameter to put the variables in the database. And no, i'm using NuSoap for creating this server :)